# Facebook comments plugin, URL aliases?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

I'm using [Facebook comments plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/) to display a comment area in each of my product pages (http://mydomain/product/:productid).

```
<div class="fb-comments"  data-href="http://mydomain/product/1" data-order-by="social" data-width="100%" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

This works great, except that each of those comment area are "instantiated" by url. Facebook knows how to retrieve each pages comments thanks to the provided URL.

Problem is, i have subdomains like http://dev.mydomain/product/1 or http://alpha.mydomain/product/1 and i would like to retrieve the comments left on http://mydomain/product/1 on those subdomains.

So, is there any way to declare "aliases" to http://mydomain/product/1, in order to retrieve the same comments on http://dev.mydomain/product/1 or http://alpha.mydomain/product/1 ?

**Edit** : Still stuck here, http://alpha.mydomain.com and http://www.alpha.mydomain.com have two different comments container, because urls are not the same...

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use JS to make a call to their Graph API? You can get the comments for a URL by making a `GET` call to their API:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/?fields=og_object{comments}&id=<YOUR_URL>&access_token=<YOUR_TOKEN>`

Facebook stores and retrieves comments based on the full URL, but you could try passing the same URL to the Facebook javascript; that *might* give you what you want. Let me know what happens.